# How to solve rendering problems in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have started developing an app with `Android Studio`, and now, for no apparent reason, one of the content xml files is having rendering problems, seemingly missing a theme or something. But in both files, the one working and the one not working, there is no reference to ANY theme in the file.

I am totally confused. This does not make any sense to me. Please let me know which files I should post so someone can take a look!

Content of the file that seems to miss the theme, or whatever:

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"

        android:columnCount="4"
        >

    <TextView
            android:text="@string/MainTitle"
            android:textSize="32dip"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="You can configure email in just a few steps:"
            android:textSize="16dip"

            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="Email address:"

            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    <EditText
            android:ems="10"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="Password:"

            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    <EditText
            android:ems="8"
            />

    <Space
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            />

    <Button
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="3"
            />
</GridLayout>
```

Error:

```
 Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme (28 similar errors not shown)
```

Comment: please add your code to question

Comment: *please don't just downvote without comment* - you don't have to mention that. People who want to downvote without giving a reason will do so anyway, and the ones who don't already know what to do

Comment: Code added of the content that has the trouble.

Comment: You should include both files **and** errog log if you are getting an error. If the files are big, try to strip it down to the bare minimum that you feel is relevant to the problem

Comment: To clarify, the problem is with rendering the layout in the graphical layout editor in android studio?

Comment: The problem is the rendering of the layout in AndroidStudio. On the phone the nrendering seems to work...

Comment: `Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout` have you tried this?

Comment: what is your activity theme?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the issue before as well, and if I remember correctly, the error was caused by not having a selected android API level (e.g., API 21: Lollipop) in project settings.

Comment: And where can I set this exactly?

Comment: My personal laptop with android studio is at home, so I will check later.  On the comment beneath mine, do you have 'null' where they show a 23?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem is a wrong theme which magically has changed with no apparent reason. Just look at the place where it says 'AppTheme' on the preview:

[image]

Click there and choose something else. This choice seems to have only an effect on the preview in AndroidStudio, not when running the real app. This is done somewhere else; I still have no clue how and where this is done...